# How can I lengthen the grace period for newly-uploaded members

Tags: civimember, status

I just uploaded thousands of new members from a spreadsheet. CiviCRM default grace period for memberships is 1 month. I tried changing it to 3 months in Member Status Rules. Members with end dates within one month are marked Grace, but members with older end dates in the last 3 months are still marked as Expired.

Am I doing something wrong or are uploaded members treated differently from normally-entered members?

I'm using CiviCRM with WordPress.

Comment: You may need to clarify the question. Are you saying that some of the uploaded members fell outside the 1 month grace period, and now that you've changed the grace period, their status isn't being updated to now make them "grace"?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SE!  Membership statuses are normally updated by the "Update Membership Statuses" scheduled job.  You'll want to enable that under `Administer > System Settings > Scheduled Jobs` if it isn't already.

Those status rules are applied when a membership is created or updated, but otherwise, any rule changes you make won't affect existing memberships until the next run of that "Update Membership Statuses" job.

However, when that runs it normally excludes memberships that have already expired so in your case you need to run that job once with an extra parameter to force it to reconsider the expired memberships.

One way to do that is to go to `Support > Developer > Api Explorer v3`

- select the Job entity
- select the `process_membership` action
- add the parameter `Exclude membership status IDs from calculations`
- set its value to '7' (deceased)
- `Execute`

[image]

Comment: Thank you Aidan, but your suggested procedure didn't work in CiviCRM 5.58

Comment: Apologies to Aidan, figured out and followed his directions. Thanks.

Comment: Great - if that worked, please add the green tick so we know it's answered.